# PHP: Testing for the value of an array element when there is a chance that element doesn't exist

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Assume I have an array $arr. It's *possible* that it has an element with a key named 'music' ($arr['music']), and I want to test whether that value equals "classical":

```
if($arr['music'] === 'classical'){
    //do something cool
}
```

However, it's possible that $arr does not have a value with the key 'music'. In order to avoid a PHP error, I therefore do the following:

```
if($arr['music']){
    if($arr['music'] === 'classical'){
        //do something cool
    }
}
```

This seems totally ridiculous. In MY opinion, if $arr['music'] doesn't exist, then it DEFINITELY doesn't equal 'classical'. Is there a way to avoid first testing whether a key exists before testing it's value?

Comment: In some ways, it's good that the warning exists, as PHP's auto-typecasting CAN come back and bite you when you deal with `0`, `'0'`, `''` and `null`. Comparing any of those to a non-existent variable will all evaluate to true, which may NOT be what you wanted.

Comment: The above code would produce a warning notice if your error reporting is set to "all". You need to use isset() or array_key_exists() as mentioned in the below answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the key does not exist it will throw an error (or a warning).
So in order for that to happen, you have to check if it **does** exist.
Here are two ways to do that:

You can check it using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) (which will be false if `$arr['music'] == null`):

```
if(isset($arr['music']) && $arr['music'] === 'classical'){ 
    //do something cool
}
```

Or use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
if(array_key_exists('music', $arr) && $arr['music'] === 'classical'){
    //do something cool
}
```

Comment: Great, I figured there must be a way to test both at the same time with && that would avoid the error. I suppose isset is better to use if only because it's less typing.

Comment: @maxedison, thats true, but you have to be careful if you are checking if something is there and `null` bc if it is `null` `isset` would return `false`, whereas `array_key_exists` would return `true`

Answer (score 0):

I think [array_key_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution. Some people doesn't like it because it uses the '@' sign, but I find it very readable so I use it.

```
if (@$arr['music'] === 'classical') ...
```

That's all. For me, the best readable solution.